# arrays testing from main method java

Tags: java, arrays

I am having problems with arrays.

I have written a code to add the sum of all the numbers in an array and I have to test it from the main by calling on previous arrays.
But I can't figure out where I am going wrong.

```
 Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    double [] scores = new double[5];
    System.out.println(scores.length);

for(int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter " + i + "th array value");
        scores[i] = stdin.nextDouble();
    }


 double sums = sumArray(scores);
    System.out.println(sums);

 }
public static double sumArray( double[] dArray)
{
    double sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= dArray.length; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + dArray[i];
    }
    return (sum);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error stack??

Answer (score 2):

This part

```
         for(int i = 0; i <= dArray.length; i++)
```

must be like

```
          for(int i = 0; i < dArray.length; i++)
```

If you share error, we can help much.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much, this is what it was saying:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
 at r9.TestArray.sumArray(TestArray.java:54)

Comment: I also have to call an array whose type is Int, but that's not working because the method is of type double, is there anyway around this?

Comment: '      int [] data = new int[25];                              for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
  {
   System.out.print(data[i] + " ");
  }

Comment: You should use generics if you have same functionality in different methods with different primitive data types.

Comment: If it is ok, could you accept my answer?